# Dipole matrix elements through parity argument

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, parity

I am trying to find the following dipole moment matrix element $(|n,\ell,m\rangle)$.

$$e\langle1,0,0|\vec r|2,0,0\rangle$$
I believe that I can say this matrix element is zero because of parity.  The wavefunctions have parity $(-1)^\ell$ and seeing as each has $\ell =0$, they are even parity.  Then r is odd, as it sends $\vec r \rightarrow-\vec r$.  This means the entire expression is odd, therefore the matrix element is 0.

Is my reasoning sound?

Comment: Sounds good to me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Under inversion, $|n,\ell,m\rangle\rightarrow(-1)^\ell|n,\ell,m\rangle$ and so the integrand $I$ transforms as $I\rightarrow(-1)^{\ell_1+\ell_2+1}I$ where $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ are the $\ell$-numbers of the two hydrogen states in question.

So whenever $(-1)^{\ell_1+\ell_2+1}=-1$, the integral vanishes.